# C 2D-array Structs Comparison Problems

Tags: c, struct, comparison, conways-game-of-life

This is my second C assignment and we have been told to recreate a version of Conway's Game of Life.  I am using a struc (typedef) to hold my 2d array of ints for the grid created with:

```
typedef int TableType[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

HEIGHT & WIDTH are #define constants.

I am trying to use the function below to compare 2 tables.  With the following error (no matter what way I try and compare the values):

```
error: expected expression before '==' token


int compareTables (TableType tableA, TableType tableB){
    int height, width;
    for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
        for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
        if(tableA[height][width]) == tableB[height][width])
        return LIFE_NO;
        }
    }
    return LIFE_YES;
}
```

I am using Code-Blocks as my compiler and can't seem to find a way to get gccx to work. So, as far as I know 'stdio.h' is the only library I can use.

I've tried importing pointers and manipulating those with the -> operator to get the values to compare to no avail.
I also use a similar method to copy tables and it seems to compile fine.

Any suggestions??
Please be gentle I'm a nOOb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a stray paren, see my answer

Comment: Code-blocks is not a compiler, it is an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(tableA[height][width]) == tableB[height][width])
```

should be

```
if(tableA[height][width] == tableB[height][width])
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I don't learn how to type soon I might hang myself. lol.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
   if(tableA[height][width] == tableB[height][width])
```

Not

```
      if(tableA[height][width]) == tableB[height][width])
```

Your function should be:

```
int compareTables (TableType tableA, TableType tableB)
{
    int height, width;
    for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
        for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
            if(tableA[height][width] == tableB[height][width])
                return LIFE_NO;
        }
    }
    return LIFE_YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Typos are going to kill me.